# Vagrant box running in awkward state

Tags: ssh, windows-7, vagrant, virtualbox

On Windows 7 (sadly, not my choice), Vagrant 1.7.2 here.

Installed Vagrant, created a `C:\vagrant` dir and dropped into it. Ran `vagrant init` and then modified my `Vagrantfile` to look like:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
    config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
end
```

Then ran `vagrant up` and got a ton of "*Authentication failure*" messages. But then when I open my Oracle VM VirtualBox manager, I see that there is a new VM created an running:

[image]

So according to the command line output, the box failed to be spawned for some auth-related issues, but then according to VirtualBox, it is alive and well.

My questions (all too similarly related to bog SO with lots of teeny, tiny separate questions):

1. Amidoinitrite? Are these auth failure messages typical of a `vagrant up`? If not, what is going on here?
2. How can I tell if my box is actually up/alive/healthy?
3. When I try to SSH into it with `ssh -p 2222 vagrant@127.0.0.1` I am still prompted for an SSH password. This is in contradiction to what the Vagrant console output says, which indicates Vagrant should have already added my SSH private key to my local SSH config. What is going on here and what's the fix?
4. If my machine is running properly, how do I shut it down when I'm done? Via Vagrant command, or do I have to go into VirtualBox and manually click the button to power off the VM?

Comment: answer to the 3rd question. You have to ssh to port 2222 using the -p flag. i.e, ssh -p 2222 vagrant@127.0.0.1. I am not sure about your other questions.

Comment: Thanks @VineethVenugopal (+1) - that solved my `Could not resolve hostname...` SSH issue but uncovered a new one; I'll update my question in a second. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't believe the Vagrant community didn't hop on this one:

1. Yes I did it right, but Windows/Cygwin makes things weird and takes some hacking (see below).
2. Yes if it is showing as 'Running' in VirtualBox, its running.
3. `vagrant ssh`. I am then queried to enter a passphrase for a key called `C:/Users/myuser/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key`, to which I just hit the `Enter` button (so that it is blank). I am then specified for the `vagrant@127.0.0.1`'s SSH password, and I enter `vagrant`. Now I'm in. Wow that was painful to figure out.
4. Once SSHed in, `exit` will allow you to exit the Vagrant box and return to your command line/shell. Then `vagrant halt` to stop the machine. You may be prompted for the `vagrant` password for permission to shut the machine down gracefully.

**Recommendation to Vagrant:** Drop Windows support altogether and force your users to use Linux or Mac (which is Linux with hipster nonsense thrown in). If my boss knew I couldn't use Vagrant from a Windows machine he'd happily approve a Mac purchase order for me ;-).